# Why is "Int ^ Int" in Scala not exponentiation? (What is it?)

Tags: scala

^ was always supposed to mean exponentiation. But it doesnt behave that way. What does it actually mean, and are there any member functions of Int that do exponentiation (other than math.pow)?

And why was it defined that way? It gets an operator precedence lower than arithemetic operations, when all other languages give it the highest precedence.

Comment: Maybe bitwise XOR. http://www.xcprod.com/titan/XCSB-DOC/binary_xor.html

Comment: Relevant: [exponentiation in programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#In_programming_languages)

Comment: I see `**` as exponentiation more than `^`, or as a function, but that's a consequence of the languages I tend towards.

Comment: Scala language specification version 2.9, section 12.2.1 it is defined as bitwise-exclusive-or. It was not "always supposed to mean exponentiation". Ref: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf

Comment: Do you use an extreme localized version of `always` and `all other`? Java doesn't use ^, bash doesn't use it, C and C++ don't use it. Is there a language at all, which uses `^`, maybe Smalltalk, JavaScript, SQL, Basic, Prolog?

Comment: I voted you down for your first statement, "^ was always supposed to mean exponentiation". Per "user unknown"'s comment, whatever programming language you currently use might have chosen the caret (^). Perhaps you use Visual Basic? Whatever the case, the caret is far from a universal in my experience.

Comment: R and Matlab use ^ for exponentiation. The OP probably came from there

Comment: @smci this question is testament that OP, shamefully, came from BASIC.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's bitwise exclusive or.  You've probably never developed in C, C++, or Java, or... 
It's inherited from them.  I don't know how one would define what it's "supposed" to be, but there's certainly a *lot* of code written with this meaning.

Int (and RichInt) don't have an exponentiation operator.

As far as precedence goes, it's in the middle of the other logical operators, which is where it belongs given its *actual* meaning (as opposed to exponentiation).

If you really wanted to override the meaning of "^" within a restricted scope (something I do *not* recommend), I *think* you could do so using implicit parameters, thereby getting the high precedence you want.  Or, more sanely, I think you could define a "to_the" or "**" operator the same way, getting the same high precedence.

Answer (score 22):

Well, "all other languages" is a very strong statement.

'^' in Scala comes from Java (where it came from the general vicinity of the C language), and means bitwise XOR.
And it's used as XOR in various other languages as well, eg. in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Many languages have some kind of exponentiation operator: R, Matlab, BASIC, LaTeX, and UNIX's bc use '3^2', Ada, COBOL, PL/I, Python and Fortran use '3**2'.

I've seen it claimed that exponentiation is relatively rare, but I'll say in many years of programming I've never needed an XOR and it's been many years since I've needed any kind of bit operation at all -- probably back to the days when they measured RAM in KB. On the other hand, I do exponentiation quite often.

Seems to me that if I were going to use Scala as my R, I might consider something like:

```
implicit class FixPow(x: Double) { def ~^(p: Double): Double = Math.pow(x, p) }
```

which is a bit ugly, but does have a higher precedence than '*', which is what's needed. So '3 * 2 ~^ 3' evaluates to 24, as expected.

C's support for a full set of bit operations comes from the fact that UNIX was written in C.   It essentially codified assembly language patterns.